# JPA repository return type

Tags: java, spring, list

I have read that `JpaRepository` methods return a `List<MyEntity>` when more entities are requested from the database, and `CrudRepository` (which is a superinterface of `JpaRepository`) returns a `Iterable<MyEntity>`.

Why does this happen? Is there any advantage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact history behind the return types.
But I would day that they have chosen Iterable because this is the super type of the collections and you can use it in for each loops.

In JPA List is the return type of Query.getResultList() so it makes sense to follow the standard.
It's List because the result can be sorted with order by clause.

Hope this helps.